# Turn off automatically - timer

Tags: led, relay, timer, automation

I'm creating a simple circuit and I need it to turn on when I press a button and stay on for the time that I choose on the timer (choose the time on a potentiometer, and it needs to go from like a few minutes to 3 hours).
Eg. I choose 1 hour, press 'start', the light stays on for an hour and it turns off.
The problem is that I can't find a timer that would work that way, can anyone help?

Ps: I don't want to use a microcontroller

Thanks

Comment: There are hundreds of such a timers in your local hardware/lighting store.

Comment: Pushbuttons? Hours? Definitely use a microcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like an eggtimer?  Most are digital now not pots, well because long analog delays are hard.

But if you want to make one , get a [**CD4060**](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cd4060%20timer&qs=n&form=QBIR&sp=-1&pq=undefined&sc=0-12&sk=&cvid=7035A943C1004706A398832E46965AB6) and run clock with pot then choose any divider ratio, fixed or tap.

Then use a power FET to drive your load.